# What username should I use when configuring OpenSSH?

Tags: git, openssh

I've come across this error:

```
$ git fetch ssh://name@gerrit.XXXXX:XXXXX/ xxx && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
Unable to negotiate with 192.168.XXX.XXX: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

This is what they suggest on OpenSSH website:

> For the case of the above error message, OpenSSH can be configured to
>   enable the diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 key exchange algorithm (or any
>   other that is disabled by default) using the KexAlgorithms option -
>   either on the command-line:
>
> ```
> ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 user@legacyhost
> ```

It did not occur to the author of the document that it is not obvious what `user@legacyhost` should be. Could you fill this information for me? I tried my gerrit login, that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 user@legacyhost
> ```

This is just an example meaning "*if your were trying* `ssh user@legacyhost` *and saw the said error then provide the* `-oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` *option to* `ssh`.

When using ssh under the hood of git, you must provide that option through the `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host gerrit.XXXXX
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```